# Invalid HOST Header from router IP

Tags: django, security, networking

I keep getting an `Invalid HOST Header` error which I am trying to find the cause of. It reads as such:

```
Report at /GponForm/diag_Form
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.0.1:443'. You may need to add '192.168.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

I do not know what `/GponForm/diag_Form` is but from the looks of it, it may be a vulnerability  attacked by malware.

I also am wondering why the IP is from a router `192.168.0.1` as well as why it is coming through SSL `:443`

Should I consider putting a HoneyPot and blocking this IP address? Before I do, why does the IP look like a local router?

The full `Request URL` in the report looks like this:

```
Request URL: https://192.168.0.1:443/GponForm/diag_Form?style/
```

I am getting this error at least ~10x/day now so I would like to stop it.

Comment: My guess is that an internal service in your local net is sending this request. Try to find the source ip using `tcpdump`

Comment: Alright. I will look into that. Thank you for the reponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this surely represents a [vulnerability](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-10561) - someone tried to access this url on router (which usually have ip `192.168.0.1`).

It looks so because request from attacker contains `HOST` header with this value.

Maybe django is run locally with `DEBUG=True`.

You may consider running it more production wised with web-server (i.e. `nginx`) in front filtering unwanted requests with nginx config and further adding `fail2ban` to parse nginx error logs and ban ip.

Or make site available only from specific ips / ads simple authorization, i.e. Basic Auth on web-server level.

---

***Previous irrelevant answer***

[ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) option specifies domains django project can serve.

In running locally - `python manage.py runserver` or with `DEBUG=True` - it defaults to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and similar.

If you are accessing django via different url - it will complain in such a manner.

***To allow access from another domains - add them to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]', '192.168.0.1']`.***

Comment: I already have it running on Apache with `DEBUG=False`. Do you have any suggestions on where I can look to set up more protections for Apache2?

Comment: It is only available through the site server IP and the site domain in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. These errors are Django blocking the requests from the router. How is a router able to hit my server? Wouldn't it have to be on the same network?

Comment: How is it reaching django? Is it in apache `ServeName`, `ServerAlias`?

Comment: I assume you are accessing via domain name which is bound to router. Attacker can send request to router ip but set HOST header 192.168.0.1 in it.

Comment: So there is nothing to worry about as long as my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is set correctly and I have SSL set up, right? All my server permissions are set correctly.

Comment: Yes, its ok. Even with correct domain / host - requests with bad path may reach django. But wrong / bad hosts usually should be filter by web-server, via `ServerName` apache directive or `server_name` nginx one.